# How do I display a table of data when a user hovers over another table's cell?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to generate a table from a list of objects. Each row will contain only the basic information for each object. However when the user hovers over a specific cell I want a popup, that contains all the information for that particular object, to appear. Maybe the popup should be in the form of a table with all the details of some sort? How do I accomplish this? Can I use JQuery with some effects on it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [jQuery tooltip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) for this kind of thing.  You can use the bodyHandler option to execute Javascript to fill the tooltip pane, which you can arbitrarily style.  See the examples.

Answer (score 1):

yep, jQuery is great for this kind of things.

there are (at least) two ways do to it:

1. prepopulated and hidden (CSS): build on the HTML page all the popup detail tables inside the visible cells, using CSS to position them 'above' the main layer (and out of the cell), and with `display:none`, and add a `.maincell:hover .detailtable { display:block;}` to make them visible when the cursor is in the main cell.
2. AJAX: bind functions to the `"mouseenter"` / `"mouseleave"` events of every main cell, there you use AJAX to get the detail table from the server and display in a positioned `<div>`, preferably on a fixed place, or maybe a few pixels to the right of the cursor (if it's a small table).  jQuery's `$("#inspector").load(dataURL)` function makes it dead easy (where 'inspector' is the ID of the `<div>` where you insert the detail table).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You may use http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/ to accomplish  this.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a mouseover event listener - that way when they hover over the intended element your callback will be called. Inside the callback you have access to the element which triggered the event - in your case td or tr - with that get the content of the entire row using appropriate jquery selector. Then you could display a dialog and now that you have the content you can display that inside the dialog.